# material-ui-pickers v2 - problem with localization on moment

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

I use Material-ui-pickers in my react project. I use v2.2.4, becouse of Material ui v3 used in my project template. Everything is fine, but i cannot localize it. I follow the example 
https://material-ui-pickers-v2.dmtr-kovalenko.now.sh/localization/moment
I import moment/locale/pl
and then globally set
moment.locale('pl')

but console.log still shows locale is 'en' and picker didn't  change

Answer (score 0):

Pass moment instance to the MuiPickersUtilsProvider `libInstance` prop

Comment: isnt 'libInstance' prop available on v 3.0.0? I'm using 2.2.4. Using libInstance instead of moment prop doesnt do any changes for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using lib `npm i @date-io/moment moment` instead of pure moment lib.
Post your code to smooth the solution.